# Spring Batch: Avoid running a job if it's running

Tags: spring-batch

I'm launching my jobs from two entrypoints:

- From `"@Scheduled"`
- From an Controller endpoint

Here my `JobService`:

```java
@Service
public class JobService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobService.class);

    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    private Job giacTxtJob;
    private Job giacImgJob;

    public JobService(
        JobLauncher jobLauncher,
        @GiacImg Job giacImgJob,
        @GiacTxt Job giacTxtJob
    ) {
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
        this.giacImgJob = giacImgJob;
        this.giacTxtJob = giacTxtJob;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    @Scheduled(cron = "${connector.giac-img-cron}")
    public void giacImg() {
        JobService.logger.debug("Launching giac img job...");

        try {
            this.jobLauncher.run(giacImgJob, new JobParameters());
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                | JobParametersInvalidException ex) {
            throw new ConnectorFault("Something wrong launching giac img job", ex);
        }

        JobService.logger.debug("Giac img as gone...");
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    @Scheduled(cron = "${connector.giac-txt-cron}")
    public void giacTxt() {
        JobService.logger.debug("Launching giac txt job...");

        try {
            this.jobLauncher.run(giacTxtJob, new JobParameters());
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                | JobParametersInvalidException ex) {
            throw new ConnectorFault("Something wrong launching giac img job", ex);
        }

        JobService.logger.debug("Giac txt as gone...");
    }

}
```

As you can see, both `JobService.giacImg` and `JobService.giacTxt` are `@Scheduled`.

By other hand, here my Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(ControllerConstants.Job.BASE)
public class ConnectorControllerImpl implements ConnectorController{

    private JobService jobService;

    public ConnectorControllerImpl(JobService jobService) {
        this.jobService = jobService;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @PostMapping(ControllerConstants.Job.GANCIMG)
    public void giacImg() {
        this.jobService.giacImg();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @PostMapping(ControllerConstants.Job.GANCTXT)
    public void giacTxt() {
        this.jobService.giacTxt();
    }

}
```

I need to avoid to perform a job if it's been running.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Spring batch job doesn't run if passed parameters are exactly same. but if you intend to check if for some parameters you already have an executing job then you can query `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` to look for running instance using `JobExecutionDao`.

[API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/JobExecutionDao.html) for `JobExecutionDao`.